# Django Gunicorn where logs are stored

Tags: django, python-3.x, gunicorn

I have deployed my app using some [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04)

I use nginx+gunicorn (also I use systemd)

Right now everything works fine on my `dev server` 
But on production it fails with 
`Internal Server Error` when I try to download file

**How and where can I find gunicorn logs?** (I use ubuntu)

Also, this is piece of code that causes an error just in case:

```
def download_xlsx(request):
    user = request.user
    file_name = request.GET['file_name']
    file_path='main_app/static/xlsx/' + str(user.id) + '/' + file_name
    disposition= 'attachment; filename="' +smart_str(file_name) + '"'
    disposition=disposition.encode('utf-8')
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = disposition
            return response
    return projects.to_utf8_json_response('not found')
```

UPD: I tried to run `sudo journalctl -u gunicorn`

But I get as a result a huge file starting 2 month ago, so I can't go to latest logs do to it's size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't forget to set the encoding in your gunicorn service file (otherwise you can get strange Unicode errors and it looks like you are running into this issue with the function that you described above.)

```
[service]
Environment="LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8"
```

this could be a related problem to yours: 
[UnicodeEncodeError [Python3/Gunicorn/Nginx/Django]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44920866/unicodeencodeerror-python3-gunicorn-nginx-django)

Comment: I took a look at the turial that you used. Adding this line Environment="LANG=en_US.UTF-8" in the file /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service in the [Service] section should hopefully do the job

Comment: Didn't help(((  Can the fact that I use not english but russian characters be the issue?

Comment: Yes exactly pass "LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8" instead (also make sure that this locale is installed on your server)

Answer (score 21):

Seems to work like this:

```
journalctl --unit=gunicorn | tail -n 300
```

Comment: If you want real time logs: journalctl -u gunicorn -f